# How do I specify a timeout in milliseconds for connection and send for multiple TCP connections?

Tags: perl, sockets, timeout

I have multiple blocking TCP clients trying to connect and send data to servers. However each operation should not take more than 500ms because the data is time-dependent. On timeout, it should try again. I have seen the `alarm()` method, but it only accepts seconds. Is there a good way of doing this?

Comment: By using UDP isntead of TCP.

Comment: I do not own the servers. UDP is not a choice :(

Comment: Are you using a thread/process per client, or are you using `select`?

Comment: `alarm` isn't going to work with threads. See my expanded answer.

Answer (score 2):

The [Time::HiRes](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aHiRes) module gives you a function `ualarm` with microsecond granularity.

Comment: so instead of `local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die 'Timed Out'; };
  alarm 1;` I will use `local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die 'Timed Out'; };
  ualarm 500;` ???

Comment: Almost. Since ualarm uses microseconds, you'd use `500*1000`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a child process per connection, you could use [Time::HiRes](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time%3a%3aHiRes)'s `ualarm`. Otherwise, I don't see why you'd even be tempted to use `alarm`. It won't even help with threads (since the signal is sent to the process).

A better approach is to keep a note of when a connection was established, and drop the connection if you receive data from the client beyond the 0.5 seconds that follow. Time::HiRes provides a version of `time` that returns fractional seconds.

This approach works no matter how you provide parallelism (threads, child processes, `select`, non-blocking operations). It works for both TCP and UDP. And it's even portable.

If everything is in the same thread and process, you can drop dead connections sooner by scanning all connections for timeouts whenever you get data from any connection.

---

`alarm` isn't going to help you with threads.

1. Calls in threads aren't interrupted if you set the handler before starting threads.

   ```
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   use threads;

   use Time::HiRes qw( time ualarm );

   local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { };

   {
      ualarm(2 * 1_000_000);
      my $s = time;
      sleep(5);
      my $e = time;
      print "Slept for ".($e-$s)." seconds\n";
   }

   for my $thread_idx (0..1) {
      async {
         ualarm(2 * 1_000_000) if $thread_idx == 0;
         my $s = time;
         sleep(5);
         my $e = time;
         print "Thread $thread_idx slept for ".($e-$s)." seconds\n";
      };
   }

   $_->join for threads->list;
   ```

   outputs

   ```
   Slept for 2.00284504890442 seconds
   Thread 0 slept for 5.00048089027405 seconds
   Thread 1 slept for 5.00327205657959 seconds
   ```
2. Setting the handler in threads has no affect at all.

   ```
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   use threads;

   use Time::HiRes qw( time ualarm );

   for my $thread_idx (0..1) {
      async {
         local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { };
         ualarm(2 * 1_000_000) if $thread_idx == 0;
         my $s = time;
         sleep(5);
         my $e = time;
         print "Thread $thread_idx slept for ".($e-$s)." seconds\n";
      };
   }

   $_->join for threads->list;
   ```

   outputs

   ```
   Alarm clock
   ```

Comment: Firstly thanks for detailed explanation. On Windows I was creating a fixed number of blocking sockets outside of functions and and same amount of threads with a counting variable that is increased by 1 each milisecond and of course some more threads for handling each socket. As the counter reaches 500 I was closing related socket so that block was being released. And if it doesn't timeout I was resetting counter to 0. Yet I am totally confused here in Linux with perl...